# Capabilities tab Windows Phone 8.1 SDK weird

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am creating an app for Windows Phone 8. I have installed Visual Studio 2013 express Update 3. I am trying to implement a basic Text To Speech app. I have read the following documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207057(v=vs.105).aspx

I am told to set the ID_CAP_SPEECH_RECOGNITION capabilities in the manifest. I got only:
[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see your app is WinRT app. But you are trying to use documentation for Silverlight for Windows Phone.

So if you need to use Text-To-Speech on WinRT you can start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.speechsynthesis.aspx) 
And if you need to use Speech Recognition on WinRT you can start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.speechrecognition.aspx)

Or you need to create new Silverlight for Windows Phone project.

Answer (score 1):

By the look of the screenshot, it is clear that you are trying to create an app in WinRT based platform.

The link provided by you is for Silverlight based Platform.

> Applies to: Windows Phone 8 and Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 only

For WP8 and WP8.1 Silverlight, you have to select the project having "(Windows Phone Silverlight)" at the end.

However, in order to achieve Text To Speech in the current app you might want to have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.speechsynthesis.aspx)